# Timer schedule Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

Tags: java, android, json, timer

getting, Timer Schedule `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException`

I am using image and period objects in JSON, period object `controls the duration of image` to be visible, but I am getting Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

my `json objects` look like this:

```
{
  "image": "http://localhost/image_01.jpg",
  "period": "15000"
}
```

May I know where i am doing `mistake` and where i have to make `changes`, to get it done soon ...

Here is my `complete` code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ArrayList<String> actorsList;
    ViewFlipper viewFlipper;
    int period = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        viewFlipper = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.flipper);

        actorsList = new ArrayList<String>();

        // execute AsyncTask
        new JSONAsyncTask().execute("http://localhost/images.txt");

        // handler to set duration and to upate animation
        final Handler mHandler = new Handler();

        // Create runnable for posting
        final Runnable mUpdateResults = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                viewFlipper.showNext(); // showNext() method
            }
        };

        int delay = 500;

        Timer timer = new Timer(); // here i am getting error
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

            public void run() {
                mHandler.post(mUpdateResults);
            }
        }, delay, period);
    }
}
```

**Logcat**

```
10-10 05:22:09.196: E/AndroidRuntime(537): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-10 05:22:09.196: E/AndroidRuntime(537): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.wingnity.jsonparsingtutorial/com.wingnity.jsonparsingtutorial.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
10-10 05:22:09.196: E/AndroidRuntime(537):      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1955)
10-10 05:22:09.196: E/AndroidRuntime(537):      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1980)
10-10 05:22:09.196: E/AndroidRuntime(537):      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:122)
10-10 05:22:09.196: E/AndroidRuntime(537):      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1146)
10-10 05:22:09.196: E/AndroidRuntime(537):      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-10 05:22:09.196: E/AndroidRuntime(537):      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-10 05:22:09.196: E/AndroidRuntime(537):      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
10-10 05:22:09.196: E/AndroidRuntime(537):      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-10 05:22:09.196: E/AndroidRuntime(537):      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-10 05:22:09.196: E/AndroidRuntime(537):      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
10-10 05:22:09.196: E/AndroidRuntime(537):      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
10-10 05:22:09.196: E/AndroidRuntime(537):      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-10 05:22:09.196: E/AndroidRuntime(537): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
10-10 05:22:09.196: E/AndroidRuntime(537):      at java.util.Timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(Timer.java:526)
10-10 05:22:09.196: E/AndroidRuntime(537):      at com.wingnity.jsonparsingtutorial.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:60)
10-10 05:22:09.196: E/AndroidRuntime(537):      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
10-10 05:22:09.196: E/AndroidRuntime(537):      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
10-10 05:22:09.196: E/AndroidRuntime(537):      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1919)
10-10 05:22:09.196: E/AndroidRuntime(537):      ... 11 more
10-10 05:22:11.355: I/Process(537): Sending signal. PID: 537 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Please add the whole stacktrace and mark the line in your code where the exception occured.

Comment: where is Timer.java class and where is line no: 526?

Comment: Timer timer = new Timer(); // here i am getting error and i am not using any separate Timer class

Comment: There are two possibilities for this exception. `1) If your period value is 0 or in negative. 2)If delay time is 0 but delay time is 500 so obvious error because of period time`. So change the value of period and check it..

Comment: @X'Factor so what would you recommend me ?

Comment: @Sophie Try to change your period variable and test it. like,  int period = 1;

Comment: @X'Factor yes i made changes like int period = 1; and now not getting any error but the issue is
its changing every image after 1 second
not based on duration which i have given in json

Comment: Right now something gone a be wrong. Check this link http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html and let me know.

Comment: your `timer` immediately executes before completing `JSONAsyncTask`, so try to add your `timer` within `onPostExecute` of `JSONAsyncTask` or else do this `new JSONAsyncTask().execute().get();` to wait for `JSONAsyncTask` response.

Answer (score 1):

It is giving you this error because the time you scheduled is zero or less than zero. Try to debug and see what are the values you're passing in `delay` & `period` as parameters.